# Проблемы с дробными числами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет,
Запускаю:

```
FloatDec = 10.25689
Floa = FloaDec - int(FloaDec)
leng = len(str(Floa))
print('Floa', Floa)
print('lenght is', leng)
```

Получаю

```
number 0.2568900000000003
length is 18
```

Окуда взялись 00000000003? И как с этим бороться?
Спасибо

Comment: Никак, ограниченная точность компьютерных чисел не позволяет записывать подобные числа абсолютно точно

Comment: Можете воспользоваться модулем [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 0):

все верно написано в комментарии, не получится абсолютно точного числа, но для корректного вывода ответа используй функцию округления. Добавь эту сроку

```
FloatDec = 10.25689
Floa = FloatDec - int(FloatDec)

Floa = round(Floa, 5)
```

после своих вычислений, где 5 количество цифр после запятой